# Find and replace text within a file on OSX/bash

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to replace the text within a file with the contents of a variable $ourpath, so that a directory path is replaced.

```
    sed -e "s/__REPLACE_THIS_PATH__/${ourpath}/" com.plex.plexconnect_daemon.bash.plist  > com.plex.plexconnect_daemon.bash.plist
```

but when i run this, it just deletes the contents of the file, or is overwriting it with a zero length file.

any thoughts?

Comment: Variables are not expanded inside single quotes, only double quotes. This is basic shell scripting.

Comment: my bad, i had double quotes in my original script. i just saw something on a web page which had single which i tried. i forgot to change back. question is now updated. thanks for the headsup. but it still doesn't work with the double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect output to the input file. When the redirection happens, the file is truncated, so there's nothing to read from. Either write to a different file and then rename it, or use the `-i` option to sed:

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/__REPLACE_THIS_PATH__/${ourpath}/" com.plex.plexconnect_daemon.bash.plist
```

This will add the `.bak` suffix to the original file and put the result in a new file with the original name.

Comment: could i write the new file to a different folder? in which case, how would that look? my code below doesn't seem to work `sed -i -e "s/__REPLACE_THIS_PATH__/${ourpath}/" ./com.plex.plexconnect_daemon.bash.plist > /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.plex.plexconnect_daemon.bash.plist`

Comment: If you're using -i you don't need the redirect: `sed -i -e "s/__REPLACE_THIS_PATH__/${ourpath}/" ./com.plex.plexconnect_daemon.bash.plist`

Comment: what if i wanted to have the updated file located in a different folder, leaving the original untouched?

Comment: Then you do it like in your original code, with redirection. The only special case is when you want to overwrite the original file.